# Set Request Dialog multi-friend selector to show only users 21+

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests, multi-friend-selector

I have a request dialog within a page tab app. I'm hoping not to have to ask the user for any permissions. I'd like the user to be able to send a request to friends (the request dialog is working fine), but I want only friends that are 21+ to come up in the users multi-friend selector. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) has a `filters` parameter you can use to define which users do/do not appear in the requests dialog.

You can also request the friends_birthday permission from your users and filter out the friends who do not have a visible birthday or where it is <21 years old.

If users absolutely must not see the app if they're under 21, just restrict your entire app via the API or app settings so those users don't see the app, its content, or requests from it.

Comment: Thanks @Igy the app is already restricted to 21+. However, I was still able to search for users in my own friends list that are not 21. I didn't go through with the actual share, but in searching I could find the user in the list. I'll try actually sharing with a user that's under 21 to see if the request notification actually shows up.

Comment: Is there a specific filter I can use to prevent users under 21 from showing in the request dialog? I couldn't find info on the actual syntax, and I'm not sure exactly where to look.

Comment: If the app is restricted, requests won't be received by users that can't see the app itself - there's no specific 'under 21' filter- you'd need to manually create one after determining which friends to exclude

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom multi-friend selector for this , just like :  [mikebrevoort's](http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html) plugin, and do a check on age and send the request.